# Why is my setState updating state only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
const [invalidateCacheKey, setInvalidateCacheKey] = useState(0);



const onChangeAssignee = () => {
  setInvalidateCacheKey(invalidateCacheKey + 1);
  mutate();
};



const selectOrder = () => {
  dispatch(
    showModal('SHOOTING_OPERATIONAL_VIEW', {
      modalType: 'OPERATIONAL_VIEW',
      modalProps: {
        content: <ShootingActionsView updateOrders={mutate} onChangeAssignee={onChangeAssignee} />,
      },
    })
  );
};
```

I have a functional component, I'm using useState to update the state of my invalidateCacheKey counter.

Then I have a dispatch method (react-redux) that displays a modal, I pass to the modal the callback (onChangeAssignee).

The problem is that: when the callback is fired the state (invalidateCacheKey) doesn't change inside the onChangeAssignee method (it is 0 after and before run the callback logging state inside the onChangeAssignee method), while inside the functional component (logging the state after useState declaration) the state (invalidateCacheKey) is 0 before the callback and is 1 after the callback.

I think that problem is dispatch method, it "stores" my state and it doesn't update it.

How to fix that?

Comment: Ciao, just put couple of code lines to see what you have done. Please :)

Comment: could you paste your code in the question please, having image makes it hard for us to try thing on our side, also look at this help page [mcve]

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I'm sorry, now is clear

Comment: @jonatjano you're right, check now :D

Comment: I can't help you on this one, I never used react/redux, but at least now your question doesn't get as much downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, unfortunately hooks in react are async so if you try to write something like:

```
const onChangeAssignee = () => {
  setInvalidateCacheKey(invalidateCacheKey + 1);
  console.log(invalidateCacheKey)
  ...
};
```

you will log an old value of `invalidateCacheKey`, because `setInvalidateCacheKey` is async as I told you. To get updated value in react hooks you could use `useEffect` hook like:

```
useEffect(() => { // this will be triggered every time invalidateCacheKey changes
   console.log(invalidateCacheKey) // this shows the la st value of invalidateCacheKey
}, [invalidateCacheKey])
```

As an alternative, you could use a [use-state-with-callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-state-with-callback) library. With this library you could write something like:

```
import useStateWithCallback from 'use-state-with-callback';
...

const [invalidateCacheKey, setInvalidateCacheKey] = useStateWithCallback(0, invalidateCacheKey => {
    console.log(invalidateCacheKey)  // here you have the last value of invalidateCacheKey
});
```

Note: set state reading state itself is always discouraged in react hooks. I suggest you to use this way:

```
const onChangeAssignee = () => {
  setInvalidateCacheKey(invalidateCacheKey => invalidateCacheKey + 1);
  ...
};
```

or

```
const onChangeAssignee = () => {
  let appo = invalidateCacheKey;
  setInvalidateCacheKey(appo + 1);
  ...
};
```

**EDIT**

Now lets say you need to use `invalidateCacheKey` in `onChangeAssignee` function. Lets suppose you worte code like this:

```
const onChangeAssignee = () => {
  setInvalidateCacheKey(invalidateCacheKey + 1);
  dostuff(invalidateCacheKey) // dostuff takes an old value of invalidateCacheKey so it doesn't work
};
```

You can solve this by moving `dostuff` into `useEffect` hook like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   dostuff(invalidateCacheKey) // here dostuff works because it takes last value of invalidateCacheKey
}, [invalidateCacheKey])

const onChangeAssignee = () => {
   setInvalidateCacheKey(invalidateCacheKey => invalidateCacheKey + 1);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Giovanni! I know what is useEffect and how to use his dependency's array but I don't understand: where I need to put useEffect and how it helps me?

Comment: Ciao, my answer is just to remark that what you wrote here "when the callback is fired the state (invalidateCacheKey) doesn't change inside the onChangeAssignee method (it is 0 after and before run the callback logging state inside the onChangeAssignee method)," is incorrect because state infact changes on `onChangeAssignee` but you cannot log it because `setInvalidateCacheKey` is async. Putting `useEffect` in component you showed in code example allows you just to check that `invalidateCacheKey` is setted by `setInvalidateCacheKey`.

Comment: Ok right, but it doesn't resolve my problem, I can check using useEffect when the state changes but i can't use the new value of my state inside the onChangeAssignee

Comment: Yes you cannot use `invalidateCacheKey` directly, but in ` onChangeAssignee` you have all the data you need. Because you know that in `onChangeAssignee` function,` invalidateCacheKey` will be incremented by 1 so infact you know what will be the next value of `invalidateCacheKey`. So a possible solution could be copy `invalidateCacheKey` into a var, increment by 1 this var and use it for your scopes. Something like `let appo = invalidateCacheKey; appo = appo + 1;` and now you can use appo like it was `invalidateCacheKey`.

Comment: I just try but the problem is about when the callback has fired again: "appo" is again equal to 0, and doesn't update :(

Comment: Ok, let me see your code better. Do you have a github repo to share? A codesandbox in which I can reproduce your error?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't show you the repo. I think that the problem is about pass the callback inside the dispatch method, in the dispatch method the state is stored but can't see for changes

Comment: Ciao @Itsfilippinifra, I updated my answer with a possible solution for problem you described in comments.

Comment: Ciao Giovanni. Many thanks for your support. I work all day around this problem and I understand that the problem is about react-redux: when I pass the onChangeAssignee method as prop to ShootingActionsView component the method is "stored" and, if another component change the state, the onChangeAssignee is re-rendered but the new onChangeAssignee method is not passed to ShootingActionsView component, so is re-rendered only in my parent component and not inside  ShootingActionsView component, that "store" the old state and so set the wrong state

Comment: I'm happy that you solved! Sorry if I was not totally useful... Ciao :)